# Why geom_bracket is not allowing me to plot a bracket?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a bracket using `geom_bracket` for my first two groups of countries the United Kingdom (UK) and France (FR). I use the following code and it plots the three estimates:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

    df %>%
      ggplot(aes(estimate, cntry)) + 
      geom_point()
```

However, whenever i add the `geom_bracket` as below, i get an error. I tried to get around it in different ways but it is still not working. Could someone let me know what i am doing wrong?

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(estimate, cntry)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_bracket(ymin = "UK", ymax = "FR", x.position = -.75, label.size = 7,
               label = "group 1")
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
structure(list(cntry = structure(1:3, .Label = c("BE", "FR", 
"UK"), class = "factor"), estimate = c(-0.748, 0.436, 
-0.640)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(
    cntry = structure(1:3, .Label = c("BE", "FR", "UK"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi, I actually don't know how to make vertical brackets but what is wrong there is that ymin, ymax and x.position are not arguments of geom_bracket()

Comment: "an error". what is the exact error text?

Comment: @Bastien i am surprised that there is not because i used this code for a different script and it worked perfectly fine: geom_bracket(xmin = 2008.5, xmax = 2011, x.position = 85, label.size = 7, label = "Group 1")

So there is xmin and xmax but not ymin and ymax which i did not know before.

Comment: @masher here is the error: Error in data.frame(label = label, y.position = y.position, xmin = xmin,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty damn late at that, but I figured out a workaround for this. I though that I might as well post it here in case anyone finds it useful.

Firstly, as Basti mentioned, **ymin**, **ymax**, and **x.position** aren't arguments that can be used - you have to use **xmin**, **xmax**, and **y.position**. Now, won't this only work for a flipped graph (i.e. x = cntry, y = estimate)? Yes, it will. However you can easily get around this by using **coord_flip()**.

Secondly, it turns out that geom_bracket doesn't inherit the data description (df) and won't run without it being defined inside it. Why? No idea. But this is what was causing the error. Additionally, for some reason, merely defining the data isn't enough, a label must also be added. Not a problem here, just thought I might mention it for dumb people like me who decided to use geom_bracket to add brackets to stat_compare_means.

Here's an example of the OP that should work, along with data generation:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(tibble) #I like tibbles

df <- tibble(cntry = factor(c("BE", "FR", "UK")), 
             estimate = c(-0.748,0.436,-0.64)) #dataframe generation

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(cntry, estimate)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() + #necessary if you want to keep this weird x/y orientation
  geom_bracket(data = df, xmin = "UK", xmax = "FR", y.position = -.75, 
  label.size = 7, label = "group 1", coord.flip = T) 
  #coord.flip = T reflects the added coord_flip()
```

You can then play around with y coordinates, size, etc. You can also expand the graph using **expand_limits()**.